# Character Extraction from String

Tags: r

How would you extract all characters up to a specified character? For Example given, I would like to extract everything before the "." (period):

```
a<-c("asdasd.sss","segssddfge.sss","se.sss")
```

I would like to get back:

```
asdasd segssddfge se
```

I tried:

```
substr(a,1,".")
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

any ideas?

Comment: its a csv file so there should only be one " . "

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a very basic approach:

```
sapply(strsplit(a, "\\."), `[[`, 1)
# [1] "asdasd"     "segssddfge" "se"
```

And another:

```
sub(".sss", "", a, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "asdasd"     "segssddfge" "se" 
## OR sub("(.*)\\..*", "\\1", a) 
## And possibly other variations
```

Comment: @Arun, forgot to add "`fixed = TRUE`" which was the approach I was taking based on (perhaps faulty) assumptions about the OP's data. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Using `sub`:

```
# match a "." (escape with "\" to search for "." as a normal "." 
# means "any character") followed by 0 to any amount of characters
# until the end of the string and replace with nothing ("")
sub("\\..*$", "", a)
```

Using `subtr` and `gregexpr` (assuming there's only 1 `.` and there's a definite match in all strings within the vector).

```
# get the match position of a "." for every string in "a" (returns a list)
# unlist it and get the substring of each from 1 to match.position - 1
substr(a, 1, unlist(gregexpr("\\.", a)) - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here an attempt using `gsub`

```
gsub(pattern='(.*)[.](.*)','\\1', c("asdasd.sss","segssddfge.sss","se.sss"))
[1] "asdasd"     "segssddfge" "se"
```