# R:: Substring a character till a numeric value is found

Tags: r

I want to substring the below words in R till it finds a numeric character.

```
BARCLAYS BANK PLC 6.860
```

The answer should be

```
BARCLAYS BANK PLC
```

I tired to used substr but I am not sure how to remove the numeric variables.

Comment: Essentially the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790253/character-extraction-from-string/14790291#14790291 - just changing `\\.` to `\\d` in that answer pretty much gets you there.

Comment: @thelatemail - thank you for your response and pointing me the post.

Comment: Linked duplicate I just added gives an in-depth explanation of nearly the same code as below fyi.

Comment: @thelatemail - thanks a lot. I will go thru.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by numbers till the end of the string (`$`) (this is based on the example provided), and replace by `''`.

```
sub("\\s+[0-9.]+$", '', str1)
#[1] "BARCLAYS BANK PLC" "US TREASURY"       "NEW BRUNSWICK"
```

Or using the OP's description (to keep only characters till a numeric character is found), we match all non-numeric characters from the beginning of the string (`^`), keep it in a capture group and replace with the backreference (`\\1`).

```
sub("^([^0-9.]+)\\s+.*", '\\1', str1)
#[1] "BARCLAYS BANK PLC" "US TREASURY"       "NEW BRUNSWICK"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("BARCLAYS BANK PLC 6.860", "US TREASURY 2.500", 
      "NEW BRUNSWICK 4.800")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I just edited the question. I just wanted to do for one string only. I will try the answer that you posted. However I am not comfortable with the substrings yet in R. In  case if you think that the code needs to be changed a bit, please help. Thanks again.

Comment: @Arun It should work whether you are working with a single string or multiple.

Comment: thankyou the second option has worked. Thanks a lot. I love your answers. I admire your speed of answering

Comment: Yres Akrun, it worked as you said. Thank you. I need to wait for 5 minutes to accept the answer ;)

Comment: @Arun No problem.  I also thought the first option may only work with the example you provided.

Comment: is there anyway that you can educate me by explaining the second code please?

Comment: I understand. Yes. I upvoted this. Probably they could have downvoted my question instead of your answer as I had asked a duplicate question. However the answer was really helpful.