# How do we extract characters before the meta character and discard everything after metacharacter? R

Tags: r

This is regarding R programming
My text string is

```
Application Games|Real Time|Social Media
```

Objective :- I want to keep the everything before the first occurrence of the pipe symbol and discard everything after that 
I have used

```
library(stringr)  
cat <- df$category  
matches_cat <- str_match(cat,"(\\w+)|")
```

It is working fine but when it comes to this Text string

```
E-Commerce|Cryogenesis|Real Estate
```

Output is  only the word `E`.

```
gsub("\\|w+,"",cat)
```

is also not able to replace some how.
I am totally new to R so what should i do in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R remove part of string after "."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617702/r-remove-part-of-string-after).  Another possible duplicate:  [Character extraction from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790253/character-extraction-from-string)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` to match the metacharacter (`|`) followed by rest of the characters to the end of the string (`.*`), and replace it with `""`.

```
sub("\\|.*", "", str1)
#[1] "Application Games" "E-Commerce"
```

This can also be done with capture groups to match all characters that are not `|`, capture as a group and in the replacement use the backreference for that group

```
sub("^([^|]+)\\|.*", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "Application Games" "E-Commerce"
```

---

If we need a package solution, `str_extract` can be used as well

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "[^|]+")
#[1] "Application Games" "E-Commerce"
```

Or using `word`

```
word(str1, 1, sep="[|]")
#[1] "Application Games" "E-Commerce"
```

NOTE: Here also, I showed compact code as well as `base R` methods without splitting or looping

#### Benchmarks

```
str2 <- rep(str1, 1e5)
system.time(sub("\\|.*", "", str2) )
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.20    0.00    0.21 
system.time(str_extract(str2, "[^|]+") )
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.08    0.00    0.08 

 system.time({
 l <- strsplit(str2,"\\|")
 sapply(1:length(l), function(i) l[[i]][1])
 })
 #   user  system elapsed 
 #   0.5     0.0     0.5
```

#### data

```
str1 <-  c("Application Games|Real Time|Social Media", 
             "E-Commerce|Cryogenesis|Real Estate")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strsplit()` to separate the string, then select just the first part

```
s1 <- "Application Games|Real Time|Social Media"
strsplit(s1,"\\|")[[1]][1]
#[1] "Application Games"
```

To apply this to a vector of strings you can use `apply` to extract the first element of each slice.

```
l <- strsplit(str1,"\\|")
sapply(1:length(l), function(i) l[[i]][1])
#[1] "Application Games" "E-Commerce"
```